# What is the difference between $PATH and $fpath?

Tags: macos, path

When I type `echo $PATH` and `echo $FPATH` I get different outputs. What are the differences between `$PATH` and `$FPATH`?

I use Mac OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Why do you expect two different variables to contain the same value?

Comment: Be careful with uppercase lowercase letters there. Shell variables are case sensitive, so `PATh` and `PATH` are different things.

Answer (score 17):

`FPATH` is the search path for function definitions.

> **FPATH**  The search path for function definitions.  The directories in this  path  are searched for  a  file  with the same name as the function or command when a function with the -u attribute is referenced and when a command is not found.  If an  executable  file  with the name of that command is found, then it is read and executed in the current environment. Unlike PATH, the current directory must be represented explicitly by  .   rather than by adjacent : characters or a beginning or ending :.

-- From the [mac developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ksh.1.html)

In addition to being used by `ksh` as @robmayoff noted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451076/1445460). [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) also uses it.

Answer (score 4):

All shells on Unix-like systems search `PATH` for an executable to run as a child process.

The Korn shell( `ksh`) searches `FPATH` for a file defining a shell function to load and execute in the current process.

The Z shell (`zsh`) searches `fpath` for a file defining a shell function to load and execute in the current process. See [`Autoloading Functions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions).

Comment: lowercase `fpath` definitely means something in zsh: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Both are different environment variables and their value may not be same.

Also, see this link about [environment variables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.bpxb200/envpro.htm)

`FPATH
    Contains a list of directories that the z/OS shell searches to find shell functions.`

`PATH
    Defines the default command path.`

Comment: What is the difference between exposing some functionality as a function or simply as an executable script in the `PATH`?

Comment: Do you mean specifying function name in `PATH`? Where will be function definition stored and how that will be sourced? In which language function? Will be `bash`, `csh` or `zsh`?

Comment: No, I mean: "I want to have the feature X. Should I implement the functionality in an executable file in `PATH`, or should I implement the functionality inside a function?". What are the use cases for each one?

Comment: It depends on use case. If feature X will be separate command or executable file, then you can create a new executable file and copy it into one of the existing path in `PATH`. Or add your path containing your executable into `PATH` variable.

Comment: Generally, it might not be possible to implement in an executable file in `PATH`. Not all files will be in your control.
It is very difficult to implement inside a function (by function, I mean function in shell) in `PATH`. Because here, you have to source definition in your shell. However, it would be very easy to define function in profile files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` etc.) Then, that function would be available to that particular user.
If you want for all the user, then you need to write in a shell file and  include in standard path of `PATH`.